# Google Contact API v3 via JavaScript not creating Contact

Tags: javascript, google-contacts-api

I wonder if you can help, please.

I am trying to use the Google Contact API v3 via JavaScript to create a Contact, with the following default ATOM+XML string:

```
  var resource = '<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"    xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">  <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"    term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>  <gd:name>     <gd:givenName>Elizabeth</gd:givenName>     <gd:familyName>Bennet</gd:familyName>     <gd:fullName>Elizabeth Bennet</gd:fullName>  </gd:name>  <atom:content type="text">Notes</atom:content>  <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work"    primary="true"    address="liz@gmail.com" displayName="E. Bennet"/>  <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"    address="liz@example.org"/>  <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work"    primary="true">    (206)555-1212  </gd:phoneNumber>  <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home">    (206)555-1213  </gd:phoneNumber>  <gd:im address="liz@gmail.com"    protocol="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#GOOGLE_TALK"    primary="true"    rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"/>  <gd:structuredPostalAddress      rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work"      primary="true">    <gd:city>Mountain View</gd:city>    <gd:street>1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy</gd:street>    <gd:region>CA</gd:region>    <gd:postcode>94043</gd:postcode>    <gd:country>United States</gd:country>    <gd:formattedAddress>      1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View    </gd:formattedAddress>  </gd:structuredPostalAddress></atom:entry>';
```

and the following request:

```
 gapi.client.request({
      'path': '/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full',
      'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml', 'GData-Version': 3.0 },
      'method': 'POST',
      'body': resource,
      'callback': writeResponse
    });
```

The raw response I get back seems to say at the end that it is created OK:

```
{"gapiRequest":{"data":{"body":"\n\n http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/martinkeywood%40gmail.com/base/2c9884718f97c163\n 2016-03-22T10:23:42.228Z\n 2016-03-22T10:23:42.228Z\n \n \n Notes\n \n \n \n \n Elizabeth Bennet\n Elizabeth\n Bennet\n \n \n \n \n  (206)555-1212 \n  (206)555-1213 \n \n  1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View \n 1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy\n Mountain View\n CA\n 94043\n United States\n \n\n","headers":{"ETag":"\"Q3w5cDVSLit7I2A9XRNbFkkIRQY.\"","Vary":"X-Origin","Content-Type":"application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8","Date":"Tue, 22 Mar 2016 10:23:42 GMT","Expires":"Tue, 22 Mar 2016 10:23:42 GMT","Cache-Control":"private, max-age=0","Server":"GSE","Transfer-Encoding":"chunked"},"status":201,"statusText":"Created"}}}
```

but the contact is not appearing in my google Contacts at all.

Any ideas, please??

Comment: OK I have found out that it is adding them, but in 'Other Contacts'. How can I get it to default into the main My Contacts group?

Comment: `<gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false" href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/{userEmail}/base/{groupId}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

For creating contact into "All Contacts" group you need to assign "groupMembershipInfo" in your contact XML data.

```
"<gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted=\"false\" href=\"http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/{USER EMAIL}/base/6\"/>"
```

Even you can also get all of your group id using [Google Contacts API Version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/). See the "Working with contact groups" section. After getting the list of all your groupMembershipInfo, you can create your contact to your desire group by providing the groupId to the above line of code in the place of "6".